"File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module." & autocomplete not working
I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find away to resolve this issue. I can easily hide the error message by adding "javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false. But that doesn't fix the autocompletion.
"File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module" error in js file
When I attempt to type app.get or app.listen nothing appears and usually when I add a bracket it autocompletes with app.length. I't really pain full and I'm not sure how to solve this & it's effecting already existing projects.
What may have caused this issue
Right before this issue appeared I had accidentally npm init -y & npm i typescript --save-dev in my home directory (iMac). I deleted the nodemodules and also the package.json files, then I experienced this issue.
I've tried:

"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false
Disabling all extensions & reinstalling VSCode
Verifying that "type": "module" isn't in the package json
installing "@types/node"
uninstalling typescript globally
restarting my iMac


This issue occurred when VS Code released their new update.
To fix this, you have two options.

Downgrade to vscode 1.93.1
Install npm packages @types/node, @types/express to the project dev dependency

In my case, I used the first option.
I created an issue in the vscode's official github account. You can find more details here
You can download vscode version 1.93 from this link
Hope this helped you.
